# How to refresh only a particular tab in DEFAULT browser, other tabs should not refresh

Tags: browser, vbscript

My default browser is launched when a batch calls this VB Script and refreshes as the application does not open instantly and needs refresh. But it is refreshing all the tabs. I want the particular tab to get refreshed with this particular URL and once the application is  open the refresh operation should stop. can it be done within this VB script.

My code:

Option Explicit

```
Dim myowmObj
Dim ObservedPort
Dim Counter

Set myowmObj=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ObservedPort = WScript.Arguments(0)
myowmObj.Run "http://localhost:"&port&"/HatsDemo"
  'Wait for 3 seconds
  Wscript.Sleep 3000

  Counter = 20
  Do While Counter > 0
        Counter = Counter - 1

        'Send the F5 key for a refresh
        myowmObj.SendKeys "{F5}"
        'Wait for 2 seconds
        Wscript.Sleep 2000
  Loop
```

Comment: Done Mofi, delete comments pls

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Do 
    Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
    Count = 0
    For Each window in AllWindows
        If window.locationname = "Newest 'vbscript' Questions - Stack Overflow" or window.locationname = "website2.com" then
            window.refresh2 3
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next
    If Count = 0 then Exit Do
    Wscript.sleep 5000
Loop
```

Using the Shell object from the Window's Shell and the web browser object.

Comment: can you please explain  2 and 3 in this statement window.refresh2 3

Comment: It's a updated method of Refresh. Look at the differences here as a google search would have shown you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752099(v=vs.85).aspx. As the parameters have changed for the COM call it can't update the original function, hence the new name.

Comment: 1. This not refreshing the page. I added  -- myowmObj.Run "http://localhost:"&port&"/HatsDemo"   before it to first open the page. 2. Also the loop is taking the control inside windows file explorer directory from where I am running the script. It is not controlling any tab of any browser 3. The counter is increasing so how to come out of loop.